# Ansible playbook indentation issue

Tags: ansible

I am starting out w/ Ansible and am working with roles for the first time. I have a main playbook that's just supposed to distinguish between Ubuntu and CentOS when installing Docker, but for some reason I can't get it to work. Is it the indentation?

```
- name: Install Docker for Ubuntu and CentOS
  hosts: all
  remote_user: xyz

  tasks:

    - name: Import tasks for Ubuntu
    - import_tasks: ubuntu_Docker.yml
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"

    - name: Import tasks for CentOS
    - import_tasks: centos_Docker.yml
      when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS"
```

```
The error appears to be in 'filelocation': line 9, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


   - name: Import tasks for Ubuntu
     ^ here (points at the n)
```

tried many indentations, just can't get it to work. It's probably trivial, but again: New to this, and a bit confused...Thx in regards.

Comment: Your playbook does not respect yaml and/or ansible syntax. Please [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and pay attention to indentation and new lines. You should also read through the [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks) to learn the basic concepts and syntax. You can validate your playbooks with [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) prior to posting.

Answer (score 0):

No hyphen(-) for import_tasks. Check the example at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/import_tasks_module.html

```
---
- name: Install Docker for Ubuntu and CentOS
  hosts: all
  remote_user: xyz

  tasks:

    - name: Import tasks for Ubuntu
      import_tasks: ubuntu_Docker.yml
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"

    - name: Import tasks for CentOS
      import_tasks: centos_Docker.yml
      when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS"
```

Comment: I see, thanks. I tried that, but now it points to the - of name infront of Import tasks for install docker at the beginning

Comment: Probably indentation in the beginning too. Just edited the indentation.Pls check now

Comment: Tried it, still points at - name in the first line. Thanks already for the help, I just wanna import these 2 tasks, idk why it still doesn't wanna work.

Comment: @ViewCello12 Do you think "---" missing at the beginning is causing the issue